# How to invoke exception for Subject Observer in map?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

I have this 0bserver subject:

```
public subject = new Subject<any>();
```

I push message like this:

```
this.subject.next({value : 1});
```

Then I try to do the following:

```
this.subject.map(data => {
      if (!data || !data.value) {
        throw new Error('No value, no function...');
      } else {
        return data;
      }
    }).subscribe((data: IFilterCustom) => {
      // WORK HERE WITH FILLED DATA
}, err => {
  console.error('Error');
});
```

I try to check if incoming data not contains `value` I invoke exception. How to do that?

Comment: So, I want to be ensure that in subscribe result I have real data to call  `this.subject.next()`, that is why I tried to check before in `map`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the latest rxjs you do this using pipes:

```js
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators'
import { of } from 'rxjs'

this.subject.pipe(
  map((data) => {
    if (!data || !data.value) {
      throw new Error('No value, no function...');
    } else {
      return data;
    }
  }),
  catchError(() => {
    console.log('Error')
    return of(null) // Be sure to return an observable here! The 'of' function creates an observable out of the argument
  })
)
```

The `catchError` part will be called once an error has been thrown in the observable. This is also useful to catch any network errors in requests.

If you don't need error handing and you just need the subject not to emit values, then you can use filter

```js
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators'

this.subject.pipe(
  filter((data) => {
    return (data && data.value)
  })
)
```

Comment: I dont want that subscriber gives value if error arises in `return of(null)`. Not if  I use I return of(null) it gets into subscribe(){} below

Comment: So you probably don't need error handing. In this case I can recommend using the `filter` operator. I'll update my answer in a minute